# Amazon instance rebooted without any intimation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

One of my amazon ec2 instance has been rebooted on yesterday night around at 22:40 without any intimation and its rebooted automatically. When i checked the log file says that,

```
Jan 12 22:40:07 impel1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="2.0.2" x-pid="960" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"][x-configInfo udpReception="No" udpPort="514" tcpReception="No" tcpPort="0"] restart
Jan 12 22:40:07 impel1 kernel: rklogd 2.0.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
```

Please suggest me what could be the reason to reboot.

Answer (score 3):

It probably was either a case of [scheduled maintenance](http://aws.amazon.com/de/maintenance-help//192-1210746-3294527) (you should have gotten a notification) or simply a case of "shit happens" - possibly a hardware failure.

Answer (score 2):

> One of my amazon ec2 instance has been rebooted on yesterday night around at 22:40 
>   without any intimation and its rebooted automatically

What is "intimation"?

Anyhow, you think Amazon servers never fail? There can be a ton of reasons for that - maintenance, moving the VM, some node jsut crashing.

You do not pay amazon for 100% uptime - you pay them to keep the machine alive via restart when shit like that happens.

Comment: I think intimation  = indication (in this case)

Comment: I thought "Information". Just no idea.